# Makefile Issue linking Zeromq libs on Linux

Tags: c++, makefile, zeromq

I'm working on a project and trying to compile my code. I just moved this code from windows (VC++) to linux and it worked fine on windows but I can't get it to compile on linux.

The program uses zeromq for TCP connections and I am getting multiple errors when I build.  Errors of the type:

```
/usr/local/include/zmq.hpp:372: undefined reference to `zmq_bind'
/usr/local/include/zmq.hpp:415: undefined reference to `zmq_msg_send'
```

I've installed zeromq via its tarball on my linux machine, and manually added zmq.hpp to the /usr/local/include folder.  I suspect that I am doing something wrong in my makefile and thats why I am getting these errors.

I am somewhat weak in creating makefiles so I would greatly appreciate if someone can take a look for me and tell me if there is an obvious issue with my makefile that is causing these issues.  Here is my makefile

```
C = g++
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++11
LFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib/

INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/

LIBS = -libzmq.la

SRCS = main.cpp NetworkTestServer.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

EXECUTABLE = tester

all: $(SRCS) $(EXECUTABLE) 

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(EXECUTABLE) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(LIBS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Thanks much

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You don't link the `.la` file.  That file is a special description of the library produced by libtool, not the library itself.  You link the `.a` file.  And, the syntax you are using is incorrect; see Tyler's answer.

Comment: Thanks KillianDS I didn't think it was really a duplicate cause I was specifically asking about my makefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like your `LIBS` definition is wrong.

Typically, the `lib` part is omitted, along with the extension. So, try something like:

`LIBS = -lzmq`

If that doesn't work, ensure that this library is contained in the location as specified by your `LFLAGS` variable.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I had that configuration initially but the same issues occurred.  I just switched the LIBS = -lzmq but i'm still getting the same errors.  I will post the contents of my folder defined in LFLAGS

Comment: The folder referenced in LFLAGS looks like:           '/usr/local/lib$ ls
libzmq.a   libzmq.so    libzmq.so.3.1.0  python2.7
libzmq.la  libzmq.so.3  pkgconfig        python3.3'

Comment: Your link line is wrong.  You have `$(CC) $(EXECUTABLE) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(LIBS)`.  It should be `$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)`.  Also your compile line is wrong; you're missing the `-c` flag.  It should be `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<`.  If this doesn't help please update your answer with a cut and paste of the actual link line that make prints out before you get the error so we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: THANKS!!  Compiled successfully with no errors after adding your last change combined with changing the LIBS = ...  Thank you all for your help, this is much appreciated.

Comment: Just one last question, how did you determine the order of the link line vars as well as the compile line?  All the makefile examples i see use different orders for those and don't really explain the train of thought behind them, so for future reference please share. Thanks